# Client or server validation doesn't work with Data Annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm developing a MVC 4 application with Entity Framework 6 and encountered a problem with Data Annotations. No matter what annotation I use, it isn't validate.
I'm using the following view model to render a form:

```
public class UserViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

In the view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

And it gets rendered:

```
<label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
<input class="text-box single-line" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

When I click the submit button the client validation doesn't get triggered and in the controller the ModelState.IsValid is true.

**UPDATE:**

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int? Id)
        {
            var model = _userService.GetUserById(Id);
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(UserViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
            {
                _userService.Save(model);
                return View(model);
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the code from your controller action?

Comment: Did you include the javascript file at the view?

Comment: Are you loading the form through ajax?

Comment: @Fals : Yes, I included this javascript:
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

Comment: @CodingDawg : no, not with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you POST to your controller, you map to `User` object, not to `UserViewModel`. This is one of the reasons your server-side validation is not triggered.

As for the client-side validation, I'm not sure, but could be just the same error - your view is based on `User` type, rather than on `UserViewModel`.

So your controller should look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int? Id)
{
    var model = _userService.GetUserById(Id);
    var viewModel = new UserViewModel() 
        {
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName,
            // other properties
        };
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
    {
        var model = new User()
        {
            FirstName = viewModel.FirstName,
            LastName = viewModel.LastName,
            // other properties
        };

        _userService.Save(model);
        return View(model);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

And top of your `Edit.cshtml` you should have `@model UserViewModel`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yesterday I has UserViewModel as you said, but trying to fix the issue I changed it to User and forgot to change it when I was copying it here. It acts the same.

Comment: In that case you need to show us full listing of your view and classes, otherwise not enough info to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After recreating my project I found out that the problem was the Ninject.Web.MVC dll. I didn't use this dll in my project so I removed it and it worked.